# Why don't Sefardim use Honey on Rosh Hashanah?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, rosh-hashanah-new-year

I was told there are Sefaradim who do **NOT** use Honey on Rosh Hashanah. What is the reason for this custom?

Comment: who told you that? never heard of it. on the other hand I can't remember the source of this custom

Comment: are you aware of how flawed your logic is? you are asking why a group of jews **didn't adopt** a custom. Why don't **you** have a custom to stand on your head for three hours a day? neither are *halacha*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.midrash.org/halakha/roshana.html

> Ashkenazim have the Minhag of dipping the Hamotzi in honey on Rosh
>   Hashana, and this is the appropriate custom according to Ashkenazi
>   tradition. According to the BEN ISH HAI, the Hammosi must be dipped three times in sugar and three
>   times in salt. Salt must be used because the table is likened to the
>   altar and the Hamotzi to the offering thereon. And on this it is
>   written: "... With all thine offerings thou shalt offer salt". Another
>   reason for the use of sugar instead of honey is that it is further
>   written in connection with the offering of incense: "...You shall not
>   offer leaven or honey..." and "...If honey were added it became
>   ritually unfit".
>
> For these reasons, the BEN ISH HAI writes, that the apples that are eaten prior to the meal
>   should be cooked in sugar and not honey. It follows logically, in such
>   a case, the symbolic request (that our year should be sweet) that is
>   recited with it, should not include the term "KaDevash" ("like
>   honey").

Comment: Shoot, stole my thunder. I found the same thing, just didn't want to quote it in full. ;-)

Comment: No thunder was stolen (_l'havdil_)! We have all gained thunder - @HodofHod and GG independently, and the rest of us by reading your contributions.

Comment: Isn't the honey referred to in the verse date honey rather than bee's honey?