# what sources discuss dipping challah in both salt and honey or only honey during rosh hashanna?

Tags: minhag, rosh-hashanah-new-year, challah-shabbat-bread, salt, honey

Many people dip their bread in only honey over rosh hashanna but I was under the impression that one should dip in both salt and honey. What sources discuss either dipping in both salt then honey or only in honey?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10336/759

Answer (score 1):

[Levush 583:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9223&st=&pgnum=207):

> .ומנהג אשכנז מטבילין פרוסת הבציעה בדבש
>
> The custom in Ashkenaz is to dip the piece of bread into honey.

Note that he makes no mention of dipping into salt in addition to the honey.

[Magen Avraham 583:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.583.1?lang=bi) and [Mishnah Berurah 583:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.583.3?lang=bi) also quote this custom of dipping the bread into honey, and don't say anything about salt.

[As noted by DoubleAA in a comment, it's possible that these sources don't mean to exclude dipping in salt as well, and are simply noting the custom to dip into  honey in addition to what is normally done.]

However, as you noted in your question, some authorities do recommend dipping in salt as well:

[Kaf HaChayyim 583:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.583.4.1?lang=bi):

> ואחר פריסת המוציא מטבל הפרוסה ההיא של המוציא במלח ג"פ ... ואח"כ מטבלם בדבש או בסוקר לסי' טוב ואוכל.‏
>
> After he says *hamotzi* he dips the piece of bread in salt three times ... and afterwards he dips them in honey or sugar as a good omen and eats.

[Ta'amei HaMinhagim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=323) (in a footnote on p.310) records a custom to first dip a piece of bread into salt and eat, and then to dip it into honey and recite a *yehi ratzon*.

R. Yehoshua Mondshine in [Otzrot Minhagei Chabad paras. 131-134](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30510&st=&pgnum=95) notes a slew of chassidic sources discussing a custom to dip in both honey and salt, but does infer (in para. 133) that the Chabad custom (at least at the time of R. Yosef Yitzchak Schneersohn) was only to use honey, and not even to have salt on the table.

Comment: It's hard to read too much into their not mentioning salt. They aren't restating everything that usually happens when you break bread.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't disagree...